# How to build javascript object dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, dynamic

I am trying to create a data object that looks like this:

```
var data = [{"label":"Category A", "value":20}, 
              {"label":"Category B", "value":50}, 
              {"label":"Category C", "value":30}];
```

I have a loop so far (below) that builds it as a string, but I am wondering if there is a better way to build this using some javascript objects:

```
for (i = 0; i < doughnutData.length; i += 3) {
    if (doughnutData[i] != "" && (i != doughnutData.length - 1)) {
        var dataValue = parseInt(doughnutData[i + 1], 10);
        chartData.push('{"label":"' + doughnutData[i] + '", "value":' + dataValue + '}');
    }
}
```

Comment: Why a string? `chartData.push({label: doughnutData[i], value: dataValue})`;

Comment: Cool, didn't know you could do it like that (new to javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've actually done a bit more work pushing a stringified version - you can easily create an object:

```
chartData.push({label: doughnutData[i], value: dataValue})
```